# Data Arrangement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have output from a SQL query in this format:

[image]

Now, I want my output to look like this instead:

[image]

Please guide me on the best possible solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('2012-2013', t.Delta2012_2013, t.Percent2012_2013),
             ('2012-2014', t.Delta2012_2014, t.Percent2012_2014)
     ) v(row, delta, percent);
```

It is unclear how to calculate the total.  Is it a constant?  Is it `delta / percent` ?  In any case, you can add the appropriate calculation.